# Which of these data formats requires the least bandwidth?

Tags: json, xml, rss, atom-feed

What from xml, json, rss, atom format will generate less traffic?

Comment: Deleted the `j2me` tag since this question doesn't have anything to do with J2ME, per se.

Comment: It depends.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: How it depends? Just try to create J2ME client that can parse data from server and trying to know what format to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is to minimize bandwidth, JSON will get you the most bang for your buck out of the choices listed. All the other forms are based around XML, which has significantly higher overhead costs.

Comment: Thanks. Thats all I want to know.

Comment: if you format your xml properly (use lots of attriutes) xml and json are about the same

Comment: @Jimmy: That's somewhat true, I suppose, but I wouldn't call that "formatting it properly". That's more like forcing a square XML peg into a round JSON hole just for the sake of shaving off a few of its corners.

Answer (score 2):

If you will gzip HTTP response on a server-side, then you won't feel the difference between xml, json, rss, atom or event JSON (though json will be a tiny bit smaller), so you can choose what is more convinient to you.
If you will not gzip http response, then JSON is the right choise.

Comment: I can't control server response because it's a third party service and server doesn't gziping responses as I can see. So, my choice is JSON.
Thanks.